# How to properly adjust markers timing on a spinning D3.js map

Tags: d3.js

I have a map of a spinning globe with location markers that I created with D3. The markers appear correctly, but disappear too early and then appear too early. I'm using the `geoDistance` method and have been fiddling with the number, but if I increase that value the dots stay on the map longer only to then appear too early (before the map has spun around to reveal that part of the map), and the opposite happens if I decrease the value. Here's the code:

```html
<svg viewBox="100 0 650 650" preserveAspectRatio="none"></svg>
                    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        const width = 750;
                        const height = 750;
                        const config = {
                        speed: 0.01,
                        verticalTilt: -12,
                        horizontalTilt: 0
                        }
                        let locations = [];
                        const svg = d3.select('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
                        const markerGroup = svg.append('g');
                        const projection = d3.geoOrthographic();
                        const initialScale = projection.scale();
                        const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
                        const center = [width/2, height/2];
                    
                        drawGlobe();    
                        drawGraticule();
                        enableRotation();    
                    
                        function drawGlobe() {  
                            d3.queue()
                                .defer(d3.json, '/static/data/world-110m.json')          
                                .defer(d3.json, '/static/data/locations.json')
                                .await((error, worldData, locationData) => {
                                    svg.selectAll(".segment")
                                        .data(topojson.feature(worldData, worldData.objects.countries).features)
                                        .enter().append("path")
                                        .attr("class", "segment")
                                        .attr("d", path)
                                        .style("stroke", "#888")
                                        .style("stroke-width", "1px")
                                        .style("fill", (d, i) => '#e5e5e5')
                                        .style("opacity", ".6");
                                        locations = locationData;
                                        drawMarkers();                   
                                });
                        }
                    
                        function drawGraticule() {
                            const graticule = d3.geoGraticule()
                                .step([10, 10]);
                    
                            svg.append("path")
                                .datum(graticule)
                                .attr("class", "graticule")
                                .attr("d", path)
                                .style("fill", "#fff")
                                .style("stroke", "#ccc");
                        }
                    
                        function enableRotation() {
                            d3.timer(function (elapsed) {
                                projection.rotate([config.speed * elapsed - 10, config.verticalTilt, config.horizontalTilt]);
                                svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
                                drawMarkers();
                            });
                        }        
                    
                        function drawMarkers() {
                            const markers = markerGroup.selectAll('circle')
                                .data(locations);
                            markers
                                .enter()
                                .append('circle')
                                .merge(markers)
                                .attr('cx', d => projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0])
                                .attr('cy', d => projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1])
                                .attr('fill', d => {
                                    const coordinate = [d.longitude, d.latitude];
                                    gdistance = d3.geoDistance(coordinate, projection.invert(center));
                                    return gdistance > 1.55 ? 'none' : 'red';
                                })
                                .attr('stroke', d => {
                                    const coordinate = [d.longitude, d.latitude];
                                    gdistance = d3.geoDistance(coordinate, projection.invert(center));
                                    return gdistance > 1.55 ? 'none' : 'white';
                                })
                                .attr('r', 4);
                    
                            markerGroup.each(function () {
                                this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
                            });
                        }
                        svg.append("circle").attr("cx",600).attr("cy",500).attr("r", 6).style("fill", "red")
                        svg.append("text").attr("x", 620).attr("y", 500).text("SIMS Member").style("font-size", "12px").attr("alignment-baseline","middle")
                    </script>
```

To see how it looks on the web, you can see it on the landing page of this site: [rcrcsims.org](https://rcrcsims.org). Any tips would be appreciated!